# Gelifluction vs Solifluction

Tags: geomorphology

I'm currently studying cold environments, looking at periglacial processes.

I've been looking into gelifluction and solifluction as processes of periglaciation. The two terms seem to be used, mostly, without differentiation.

However, I am given to understand that there is a difference between the two processes. Apparently gelifluction is more distinct to periglaciation than solifluction.

Could anyone explain the difference between the two processes, if at all there is a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Solifluction is not restricted to cold climates. Gelifluction on the other hand is, it requires by definition a permanent/seasonal layer of frozen soil. In periglazial environments the porewater above the frozen ground layer becomes easily saturated. Solifluction encompasses numerous processes, Gelifluction is one of them...

The wikipedia page for Solifluction provides more information.